# Mandar mensaje de error al introducir datos incorrectos en login con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, login

Soy nuevo en esto de php.

Hice con éxito un login en php, puedo ingresar mis datos y validarlos para ver si están los datos correctos en la BD.

Pero cuando ingreso algún dato incorrecto lo único que hace es mandarme de nuevo a la pagina del login (login.php). Les muestro el código que es el que valida la información:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
header("Location: Login.php");
exit();
}

conectar();

//Seleccionamos el usuario de la base de datos
$result = mysqli_query(conectar(), "SELECT * from usuarios where Username='" 
. $usuario . "'");

//Validamos informacion correcta en caso de que sea incorrecta redirigir a 
Login.
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if($row['Password'] ==  $pass){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: RegistrarProyectos.php");
}else{
    header("Location: Login.php");
    exit();
}
}else{
header("Location: Login.php");
exit();
}

?>
```

Me podrían decir como hacer para poder mandar un mensaje de error en la misma pagina sin que se recargue o me redirija. Vi algunos con Bootstrap:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no supe como implementarlos en mi pagina ya que necesito hacer uso de un script y la verdad se me complica JS. 
La idea es que debajo del login salga uno de esos mensajes indicando que los datos del usuario son incorrectos.
El formulario lo tengo por separado en otro archivo .php.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Tendrias que hacerlo con Ajax, pero para todo esto necesitas saber Javascript.

Comment: también, en un login no se te olvide cifrar la contraseña con password_hash, miratelo, si no todas las contraseñas entraran en la base de datos con texto plano. cosa no muy recomendable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno tu pregunta es basicamente en base a experiencia, te puedo sugerir que crees una variable de sesion de la siguiente manera;

```
<?php
session_start(); //Iniciando la sesion
include 'conexion.php';

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){

header("Location: Login.php");
exit();
}

conectar();

//Seleccionamos el usuario de la base de datos
$result = mysqli_query(conectar(), "SELECT * from usuarios where Username='" 
. $usuario . "'");

//Validamos informacion correcta en caso de que sea incorrecta redirigir a 
Login.
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if($row['Password'] ==  $pass){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: RegistrarProyectos.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['fallo_login'] = 'fallo inicio de sesion, datos incorrectos';//Creamos una nueva variable de sesion
    header("Location: Login.php");
    exit();
}
}else{
$_SESSION['fallo_login'] = 'fallo inicio de sesion, datos incorrectos';//Creamos una nueva variable de sesion
header("Location: Login.php");
exit();
}

?>
```

> Nota que he colocado la creación de una nueva variable de sesión en
>   los else que pude ver que estas utilizando para redirigir al usuario
>   al login.

Entonces en tu codigo del login creas algo como esto:

```
 session_start(); //Iniciando la sesion, esto debe estar ante cualquier codigo.

 if(isset($_SESSION['fallo_login'])){
        echo "<div>Los datos introducidos son incorrectos</div>";
 }
```

Puedes también imprimir lo que contiene la variable;

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fallo_login'])){
            echo $_SESSION['fallo_login']";
}
```

Con esto estas verificando si la variable de sesión existe, de existir es porque el usuario no ha colocado los datos correctos, algo básico que puedes mejorar mucho mas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda.
Sabes como puedo aplicar lo mismo pero en vez de un login aplicarlo al enviar información de un formulario a una base de datos?(el formulario es publico así que no puedo usar sesiones.)

Comment: @AlexAlmaran si pudiera ver tu código podría analizarlo. de antemano te digo tienes algunas opciones entre ellas la respuesta del servidor, la confirmación del submit, entre otras que ahora mismo no puedo recordar.

Comment: No puedo poner el código aquí pero es muy corto tengo los $nombre = $_POST['usuario']; para traer información del formulario y para poder mandar la información a la base de datos
    $queryInsert= "INSERT INTO proyecto (nombre, lugar, imagen, 
    descripcion, imagen1, imagen2, imagen3)" . " VALUES (aqui van 
    los valores de los POST)

y tengo un if :
if (!mysqli_query(conectar(), $queryInsert)) {
    echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
}

else {
    header("Location: RegistrarProyectos.php");
    
}

Comment: Puedes aplicar el ejemplo de la session en este código por igual.